# Transient and non-dirty attribute, ember-data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I would like to declare transient attributes in my Ember models that doesn't affect the "dirty" state of the model.

At the moment, I declare them like this within the model :

```
eventId: DS.attr("string", {defaultValue: "", transient: true})
```

They are ignored in the serializer, so they wont be posted to the API :

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    serializeAttribute: function(record, json, key, attribute) {
        if (attribute.options.transient) { return; }
        return this._super(record, json, key, attribute);
    }
});
```

But the thing I also require that those properties doesn't change the "dirty" state of the object (for tracking and rollbacking without touching these).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the solution was super easy. I needed an attribute that wasn't tracked by Ember-Data (that didn't change the state and that remained untouched after a rollback).

The solution : declare the "attribute" without `DS.attr`. It is in fact a normal Ember Object property.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand.  So what to I use instead of  


`mapaLat: DS.attr()`

Comment: like you would do with every other Ember "objects", it means you'd use `mapaLat: "your value, as simple as that"` without wrapping in a `DS.attr()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way, but you can use a computed property:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  name: Ember.computed(function(key, value) {
    if (value) {
      this.set('___name', value);
      return value;
    } else {
      return this.get('___name');
    }
  }),
  age: DS.attr('number')
});
```

Then just access it in a template like normal:

```
{{input value=model.name}}
```

Caveat: you'll need to trigger the computed property to initially set the value on the model, e.g.:

```
this.store.push('person', {
  id: 1,
  age: 15,
});
this.store.find('person', 1).then(function(person) {
  person.set('name', 'Kori')
});
```

Bonus: [working jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lofovi/5/edit)

Comment: In the jsbin, the state after changing the age and rewriting the original "15" is still dirty. But it might work for my actual use case, will try this tonight !

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too. Probably Ember Data isn't smart enough to transition back to a clean state if the property reverts to its original state.

Comment: or it could be that since it's a number, and the input is a string, ember data gets confused? Will test later.

Comment: Looks like it's the fact that it's a DS.attr('number'). DS.attr('string') doesn't have the same problems. See: http://jsbin.com/batiqu/3/edit